# Using page template to fetch posts in page

Tags: php, loop

i want to display posts in wp page. to do that this is what i did i created a template named mypage-page.php and copied code from page.php to mypage-page.php

this is my mypage-page.php

```
      <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
               <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                <?php endwhile; else: ?>

                        <p>Sorry, no posts to list</p>

                <?php endif; ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->
   //   this has header and footer as well .
```

now i created a page mytest using this template ,what i expect it should list posts but it does not, please help me to understand where i'm wrong . i'm just a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use wp_query to query the database for the posts, which will be something like:

```
<?php
 $blog_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => '-1',
  'order' => 'DESC'
 );
 $blog_query = new WP_Query($blog_args);
 while ( $blog_query->have_posts() ) {
  $blog_query->the_post();
  echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
 }
 wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
```

That will display all posts with just the post title, you would need to add pagination and add more detail to the actual displayed element but should give you a head start

Comment: yes that oworked , can you tell me how can i make post title clickable to go to single.php against each post

Comment: try my edit which I have made

Comment: Perfect thank you very much , earlier today you guided me to go for custom page templates and now helped me to implement it . I've really learned something  imp from you

Comment: your welcome, I was in your shoes a few years ago so it's nice to help out others